# How does Dagger2 subcomponent inject in Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dagger-2

How can I inject dagger2 subcomponent in Fragment. I use same subcomponent in Activity and it work good. How can i initialize module in fragment.

part of my Fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    DgFirebaseSubComponent.Builder builder = (DgFirebaseSubComponent.Builder)
            ((AttendanceApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getApplicationComponent()
                    .subcomponentBuilders()
                    .get(DgFirebaseSubComponent.Builder.class)
                    .get();
    builder.activityModule(new DgFirebaseSubModule(??how can i initialize module ??)).build().inject(this);

}
```

my DgFirebaseSubComponent.java

```
@DgFirebaseScope
@Subcomponent(modules={ DgFirebaseSubModule.class })
public interface DgFirebaseSubComponent {

void inject(DgAllEmpsAbsMvvmActivity activity);
void inject(DgAllEmpsAbsListFragment fragment);

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences();

@Subcomponent.Builder
interface Builder extends SubcomponentBuilder<DgFirebaseSubComponent> {
    Builder activityModule(DgFirebaseSubModule module);
    }

}
```

my DgFirebaseSubModule.java

```
@Module
public class DgFirebaseSubModule {
private final DgAllEmpsAbsMvvmActivity activity;

public DgFirebaseSubModule(DgAllEmpsAbsMvvmActivity activity) { this.activity = activity; }


@Provides
@FirebaseScope
SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Application application) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module does not must be instantiated with an activity. I have changed DgFirebaseSubModule.java

```
@Module
public class DgFirebaseSubModule {

public DgFirebaseSubModule() {  }


@Provides
@FirebaseScope
SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Application application) {
return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }

}
```

and inject in fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

DgFirebaseSubComponent.Builder builder = (DgFirebaseSubComponent.Builder)
        ((AttendanceApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getApplicationComponent()
                .subcomponentBuilders()
                .get(DgFirebaseSubComponent.Builder.class)
                .get();
builder.activityModule(new DgFirebaseSubModule()).build().inject(this);

}
```